# Unity Cloud Build and Firebase, build than upload to storage

Tags: firebase, unity-cloud-build

Did anyone work with Unity Cloud Build and Firebase storage for builds? I'm trying to set up a hook so that when I update the repo, UCB will read that, run the build, and then send the zip file to a specific folder in my Firebase store.
Found some guides online but they're all kind of old and some points there don't align with what I'm seeing in the UCB dashboard.
Help? :pray: